# MathJax stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

MathJax stopped working again. It works fine on other sites such as math.se and cstheory.se. I tried several different browsers and operating systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies here - I inadvertently disabled MathJax on the site.

I've re-enabled it now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Sorry for breaking it in the first place :(

Comment: Apology accepted. Clearly you flipped the wrong switch trying to move [cs.SE] forward from beta, and we'll take some discomfort for that finally happening!